# How do I display certain information from SQLite Database?

Tags: python, django

I would like to display information obtained from an SQLite Database, but I would only want the data to be displayed that is related to the user.

[image]

Since the email of each user is unique, I want it to see if it matches the email of the current signed user. Below is the code for the corresponding view above

Update: I have just attempted to do a filter

```
claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.filter(email=user.email)
```

```
def newclaim(request):
  
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  if request.method == 'POST':
      name = request.POST['name_field']
      email = request.POST['email_field']
      claim = request.POST['claim_field']
      claimtype = request.POST.get('claimtype')
      description = request.POST['description_field']
      receipt = request.POST.get('receipt_field')
      cheque = request.POST.get('cheque_field')
      ins = SaveClaimForm(name=name, email=email, claim=claim, claimtype=claimtype, description=description, receipt=receipt, cheque=cheque)
      ins.save()
      print("The Data has been written")
  return render(request, 'Login/newclaim.html/', context)
```

> Working Updated view (With reference to the answer given):

```
  def viewclaims(request):
      context = initialize_context(request)
      user = context['user']
      if user.get('email', None):
        claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.filter(email=user.get('email', None))
        return render(request, 'Login/existingclaims.html', {'claims':claims, 'user':user})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

That will be something like

```py
if user.get('email', None):
  SaveClaimForm.objects.filter(email=user.get('email', None))
else:
  return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
```

Instead of

```py
SaveClaimForm.objects.all()
```

Comment: my models have the attribute 'email' but it returns an attribute error stating that there is no such attribute in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok. I edited little bit my answer. I don't know how looking your request data, context and models, so can't answer definitely. The key of my answer is to use `objects.filter` instead of `objects.all` and filter it by email value